# MVC Repository Pattern query caching issue

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, asp.net-core, repository-pattern

I am trying to build a webservice API application hosted in Azure that looks up product prices in a database. This is being developed using Visual Studio 2017 in C#.  Being relatively new to C#, MVC and .netcore (I know, not a good starting point :-)) I have been following various tutorials and following design best practice to develop the webapp. This includes using the Repository Pattern approach for creating an interface as part of the controller.

```
namespace i*******api.Models
{
    public interface IPrice
    {
        LiveProduct Find(string sku, string cCode);
    }
}
```

then

```
namespace i*******api.Models
{
    public class Price : IPrice
    {
        static List<LiveProduct> LiveList = new List<LiveProduct>();
        private readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;

        public Price(ApplicationDbContext context)
        {
            _context = context;   
        }

        public LiveProduct Find(string findSKU, string cCode)

        {
            var prices = (from m in _context.LiveProduct
                          where m.countryCode == cCode && m.sku == findSKU
                          select m).FirstOrDefault();

            return prices;
        }
```

and finally the controller...

```
namespace i*******api.Controllers
{
    [Produces("application/json")]
    [Route("api/Prices")]
    public class PricesController : Controller
    {
        public IPrice PriceRepo { get; set; }

        public PricesController(IPrice _repo)
        {
            PriceRepo = _repo;
        }

        [HttpGet("{id}", Name = "GetPrice")]
        public IActionResult GetById(string id, string cCode)
        {
            var item = PriceRepo.Find(id,cCode);
            if (item == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            return new ObjectResult(item);
        }
    } 
}
```

The code, above, works fine in principle and I can exercise this and get back the correct result the first time I call this. There is a separate webapp that updates this database and if the price is updated separately the API query above continues to return the original and not the updated results.

Having looked into and searched this issue I am assuming that there is general EF type caching going on and that I should be using something like `AsNoTracking()` or similar to prevent this caching happening? However I can't see anyway to apply `AsNoTracking()` in the above scenario (it won't let me add the `using` namespace, for example) - but this is where I guess my inexperience is really kicking in :-(

When I debug I can see the first time this runs the `_context` is created but this is not repeated on any subsequent queries. `PriceRepo = _repo` happens each time but `not _context = context`.

I would appreciate some help to resolve this and hoping it is something simple that I'm just missing.

Comment: Generally speaking, an EF context should be treated as a unit of work, if you're going to follow this pattern and use Entity Framework, meaning you should wrap the context into a using block within each repository method.

Comment: How did you configured DI container to inject the Price into the controller?

Comment: Sounds like you are registering your DbContext as singleton, which you shouldn't do. DbContext should always be registered as scoped (one instance per request)

Comment: Thanks @Tseng - could you advise how that would be done in this context (excuse the pun :-))

Comment: @Tieson T - I can undestand what you are saying and agree that is what I'm really trying to do (but not sure how to do it - would you mind sharing an example ?

Comment: Don't register your repository as Singleton. Instead `services.AddSingleton<IPrice, Price>()` do `services.AddScoped<IPrice, Price>()`

Comment: @Tseng - Thank you - that is really helpful. I did make this change and you are correct it was registered as a singleton - appears to work fine when registered as scoped

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try following

```
 var prices =
    _context
      .LiveProduct
      .AsNoTracking()
      .FirstOrDefault(m => m.countryCode == cCode && m.sku == findSKU);
```

Comment: Thanks @tchelidze, I like the way in which this is formatted and it works (the first time) ok without the .AsNoTracking() addition. However .AsNoTracking() doesn't work and fails build. I can't add 'Using System.Data' to the code in the context so it doesn't recognise it I'm afraid - not sure why?

Comment: @Huw Why can't use add `using` statement ?

Comment: I'm not sure (and that may be the problem). It doesn't allow 'Using System.Data.Entity' and doesn't recognise it. It doesn't show up on Intellisense and errors on build. I am going to re-install Entity Framework to see if that resolves it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer @tchelidze. I checked and re-installed the entity framework package for the api part of my app - after this was re-installed I was able to add the 'using Microsoft.EntityFramework' statement successfully (It didn't allow before) and your code worked - both in terms of build and the AsNoTracking doing what it should.

Comment: @Huw happy that helped